# How can I modify an existing Excel workbook with Perl?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xls

With [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel), I can create a new workbook, but what if I want to open an existing book and modify certain columns? How would I accomplish that?

I could parse all of the data out of the sheet using [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) then write it back with new values in certain rows/columns using [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel), however. Is there a module that already combines the two?

Mainly I just want to open a `.xls`, overwrite certain rows/columns, and save it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) will read in existing excel files:

```
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
# $workbook is a Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook object
my $workbook = $parser->Parse('Book1.xls');
```

But what you *really* want is [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser), which is a combination of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel).  There is an [example](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#MODIFYING_AND_REWRITING_EXCEL_FILES) near the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: I don't see any way to write to an excel book using ParseExcel

Comment: Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser will do that. you beat my edit. :)

Answer (score 9):

If you have Excel installed, then it's almost trivial to do this with [`Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::OLE). Here is the example from `Win32::OLE`'s own documentation:

```
use Win32::OLE;

# use existing instance if Excel is already running
eval {$ex = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')};
die "Excel not installed" if $@;
unless (defined $ex) {
    $ex = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
            or die "Oops, cannot start Excel";
}

# get a new workbook
$book = $ex->Workbooks->Add;

# write to a particular cell
$sheet = $book->Worksheets(1);
$sheet->Cells(1,1)->{Value} = "foo";

# write a 2 rows by 3 columns range
$sheet->Range("A8:C9")->{Value} = [[ undef, 'Xyzzy', 'Plugh' ],
                                   [ 42,    'Perl',  3.1415  ]];

# print "XyzzyPerl"
$array = $sheet->Range("A8:C9")->{Value};
for (@$array) {
    for (@$_) {
        print defined($_) ? "$_|" : "<undef>|";
    }
    print "\n";
}

# save and exit
$book->SaveAs( 'test.xls' );
undef $book;
undef $ex;
```

Basically, `Win32::OLE` gives you everything that is available to a VBA or Visual Basic application, which includes a huge variety of things -- everything from Excel and Word automation to enumerating and mounting network drives via Windows Script Host.  It has come standard with the last few editions of ActivePerl.

Comment: Moreover, you can write whole arrays into columns\rows at once and it affects the speed of writing. If that's not enough, you can also write into an excel that has a macro in it and run with that module.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX::SaveParser doesn't exist so this works much better for me.

Answer (score 3):

There's a section of the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel docs that covers [Modifying and Rewriting Spreadsheets](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#MODIFYING_AND_REWRITING_EXCEL_FILES).

> An Excel file is a binary file within a binary file. It contains several interlinked checksums and changing even one byte can cause it to become corrupted.
>
> As such you cannot simply append or update an Excel file. The only way to achieve this is to read the entire file into memory, make the required changes or additions and then write the file out again.
>
> You can read and rewrite an Excel file using the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser module which is a wrapper around Spreadsheet::ParseExcel and Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. It is part of the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/) package.

There's an example as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser) module is a wrapper around Spreadsheet::ParseExcel and Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

I recently updated the documentation with, what I hope, [is a clearer example of how to do this](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser#SYNOPSIS).

Comment: I still don't quite get this example. I can't find the  documentation for what SaveAs accepts. Is is possible to pass file handles or scalar ref instead of a filename?

Comment: Oops I realised that John McNamara included a write_to_scalar.pl file in package. Using it I was able to make a memory to memory modification of an XLS file :-D