# How to store the output of several mysql queries in two different excel sheets?

Tags: mysql, excel, shell

I have 4 mysql queries executed by shell script like `./a.sh > b.xls`. So all the data is stored as a single worksheet.

I need to slit this, so that the first 2 queries are stored in the sheet 1 and the other two in sheet 2. Also, in each sheet I would like to have the output of each query side by side, not one by one.

Is it possible to do such thing in shell scripting?

Comment: this is a bit broad. What have you tried so far? how do your queries look like?

Answer (score 1):

Best you'd be able to do from Bash is CSV output, which means you can't have multiple worksheets. Alternatively, use [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm), [Python](http://www.python-excel.org/) or [PHP](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), which do have supporting libraries for XLS output.

See also [Writing to an excel sheet using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579008/writing-to-an-excel-sheet-using-bash)

Comment: or php. or setup a data connection from excel to the mysql db