# Plot graph in an existing excel sheet using perl

Tags: excel, perl, perl-module

I have an existing excel(.xls) file with data. I need to read the data from the file and plot chart/graph based on the same data on the same sheet. Is there any methods in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module to plot graph.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) as it can just read excel files.

I would suggest you to read the excel data in and then try either of the following:

1. Create another xls file and use the [`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Chart`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel%3a%3aChart) library.
2. Create a xlsx file and use the [`Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX%3a%3aChart) library.
3. Another close option would be to read the excel in with [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel%3a%3aSaveParser) and then add the chart and save it, but with this module all original charts are lost.
4. If you are on a Windows machine you may trying to use 
   [`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aOLE).

This alternate SO post may be helpful: [How can I modify an existing Excel workbook with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368960/how-can-i-modify-an-existing-excel-workbook-with-perl)

Comment: Using the module Spreadsheet::WriteExcel will generate the graph in a new spreadsheet. But I want the data and the corresponding graph in the same sheet

Comment: i updated the post a bit. The problem is that excel is very hard to update with perl. It is easiest with access to a .net api.

Comment: if you have excel on the same mashine that you run perl (ie running this on a laptop, and not on a server, https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE may be a similar option as .net. (Ie you control excel from Perl). You can mainly record a macro in Excel, and based on that, guess how the commands should be in Win32::Ole

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang  point 3 : can u tell me how to add cart using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser??